# How to create a semi-transparent filter hover the activity?

Tags: android

I'm new in Java android developpement.

I need your help to realize a semi transparent filter hover the activity

[image]

I've already search a lot on google and stack overflow but I don't find the thing that i want to do.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use a layout that allows placing views one above other, and put a view with semi-transparent background above the main view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put frame layout on top with transparent background, and on top of that put play button layout

Looks something like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/transparent_dark_grey"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/playButtonLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Also it is good practice to use ConstraintLayout

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: See updated answer maybe it will help

Comment: Ok, this is working thanks for your quick answer 

Comment: No problem, please mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, that after some action on your screen, you want to show progress bar and hide your screen behind semi transparent overlay. So first step is to add transparent color to your app.
Lets use this one `#99000000`.
Add it to colors.xml like

```
<color name="overlay_color">#99000000</color>
```

Now, you have to add overlay view to your activity/fragment.
It will looks like that:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/src"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/src_2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/overlay_color" />
<!--Add your progress there-->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And when you show your progress, just change the visibility of overlay.

Comment: Thanks it will be very helpful for next steps 